# Jquery open this link not the others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I have a series of divs and inside each div there is a link.

What I want to accomplish is to open in another window or tab the .pdf file if the link ends in.pdf if not do nothing or something else to decide later.

The problem I'm having is that when you click on the link it will open the same document as many times as you have .pdfs on the page.

I tried replicating the problem in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/x9fo6cgk/

But it isn't working. The code works on my side.

Here is the code:

```
    $('.somelink').click(function(eventObject) {
      var elem = $(this);
      if (elem.attr("href").match(/\.pdf$/i)) {
        eventObject.preventDefault();
        elem.attr('target', '_blank');
      }
    });
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="linkholder">
      <a class="somelink" href="https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf">pdf 1</a>
    </div>

    <div class="linkholder">
      <a class="somelink" href="http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf">pdf 2</a>
    </div>

    <div class="linkholder">
      <a class="somelink" href="http://www.bing.com">.com</a>
    </div>

    <div class="linkholder">
      <a class="somelink" href="http://www.google.org">.org</a>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the behavior of this script:

https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/#preventdefault

under Magnolia CMS acts a bit weird.

So this code was used instead:

```
$(".linkholder a[href$='pdf']").attr('target','_blank').addClass('pdf');
$(".linkholder a:not(a[href$='pdf'])").addClass('generic');
```

Here is a the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/x9fo6cgk/13/

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You should just change the targets on page load if they are PDFs.

```
$('.somelink').each(function() {
  var elem = $(this);
  if (elem.attr("href").match(/\.pdf$/i)) {
    elem.attr('target', '_blank');
  }
});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/x9fo6cgk/3/

Results in this HTML:

```
<div class="linkholder">
  <a class="somelink" href="https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf" target="_blank">pdf 1</a>
</div>
<div class="linkholder">
  <a class="somelink" href="http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf" target="_blank">pdf 2</a>
</div>
<div class="linkholder">
  <a class="somelink" href="http://www.bing.com">.com</a>
</div>
<div class="linkholder">
  <a class="somelink" href="http://www.google.org">.org</a>
</div>
```

Note: Your JSFiddle did not have jQuery selected so nothing ran.

Comment: Thanks for adding the library. The problem with .each is that isn't opening a new page in Firefox it just prompts me to save the file.

Comment: @Luis: Different browsers handle downloads in different ways. Have you tried the suggestion by Guilherme Lopes?

Comment: I just replied to his post. It opens all the .pdfs on my side unfortunately.

Comment: @Luis: How are they served up? We change the response information headers when we stream back a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$('.somelink').click(function(eventObject) {
   var elem = $(this);
   if (elem.attr("href").match(/\.pdf$/i)) {
   eventObject.preventDefault();
   window.open(elem.attr('href'));
  }
});
```

Look here: https://jsfiddle.net/x9fo6cgk/6/

Comment: the fiddle works but on my side it still opens all the .pdfs at once. Thanks!

Comment: @Luis All `.pdfs` links at once? Make sure you `script` tag is before `</body>` and `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` before the `script`